# Android relative layout inside scrollview not scrolling in landscape mode

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

Hi I have put all my UI elements inside a relative layout and then put the relative layout in the scrollview to achieve screen scrolling. But the layout is not scrolling in landscape mode.What am I missing here. any idea?

Thanks,
P

**Update:** The view is not scrolling in potrait mode as well. I added some extra UI elements and the view is not scrolling in this mode either. I am using Nexus 6P phone to test it.

Here is the xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.LoginFragment"
    android:fillViewport="true"
  >


 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/login_hello"
        android:id="@+id/login_tv1"

        android:fontFamily="Roboto"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"

        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/login_text"
        android:id="@+id/login_tv2"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login_tv1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/login_tv1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/username_et"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="@string/login_username"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:width="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/password_et"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username_et"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username_et"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username_et"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username_et"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/username_et"
        android:password="true"
        android:hint="@string/login_password"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rememberme_switch"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password_et"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password_et"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password_et"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password_et"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/password_et"
        android:hint="@string/remember_me"
        android:textOff="@string/off"
        android:textOn="@string/on"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:showText="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:trackTint="#000000"
        android:textColorLink="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/help"
        android:id="@+id/help_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rememberme_switch"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rememberme_switch"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/help_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/rememberme_switch"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/error_tv"
         android:textColor="#f92626"
         android:fontFamily="Roboto"
         android:textSize="16dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/password_et"
         android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password_et"
         android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/login_button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>`
```

Comment: What happens when you change the `RelativeLayout` width/height to `wrap_content`?

Comment: Hi, Are you try to put ***RelativeLayout*** inside ***LinearLayout*** look like : ***ScrollView*** -> ***LinearLayout*** -> ***RelativeLayout*** -> your content

Answer (score 0):

I just tested a similar layout and it's scrolling fine. What's inside the scrollview needs to be larger than the screen size for the scroll bar to show. Or you could set a size for the scrollview then as long as the content inside is larger it will scroll.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.LoginFragment"
    android:fillViewport="true"
  >
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add a lot of text here so the text will fill page and scroll aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```